# Codeigniter login using tank auth fails

Tags: php, codeigniter

So i've been using the Tank Auth login library fine then today all of a sudden it stops working, does not allow me to login: basically it will not even tell me if the password is incorrect it simply refreshes the page on the login script.

I didn't even change anything it just stopped working which is really unsettling.

No Apache error logs, no JavaScript errors, nothing, just does not authenticate.

Does anyone know how I can go by debugging this issue? Has anyone had this happen before?

Comment: Perhaps this is an issue with your cookies? This can also happen when you block Javascripts.

Comment: Did the database die?

Comment: @stormdrain the DB is still intact I can still register as a user

Comment: @q3d i think it is a cookie issue i tried to clear cookies but it still persists, not sure what else I can do.